# How to update all instance of an item type with an ImpEx without using unique modifier?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I need to update all instance of an item type (for exemple Employee) but I don't want to update each row using the `uid[unique=true]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this with the modifier `[batchmode=true]`. Because you still have to include an unique attribute, you have to set the item that will be updated.

```
UPDATE Employee[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique=true];myAttribute
;Employee;""
```